# When installing apps, they don't appear

Tags: user-interface, install

I am new to Linux and I have doubts when installing programs in the Elementary operating system.
When I install a program (for example, using "snap") it doesn't appear until after I restart the system. This is normal?. Is there a way to make it appear without having to reboot the system? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is normal.
Instead of restarting, you should just log out. It gonna be faster.

Btw, try to find app in AppCenter before finding it in Snapd.